# Why does this for loop equal 12?

Tags: java

I'm sorry for the novice question. I just can't trace this *for loop* correctly to see why `x = 12`.

```
int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        x++;
```

Comment: try printing out i, j and x every time x++ is executed

Comment: make step by step debug to understand totally.

Comment: second `for loop` is looping 4 times for every `i` in `first loop`. First loop has 3 iterations. 4x3 = 12

Comment: What do you think the result should be? Why?

Answer (score 6):

3 iterations of 4 where x is incremented.

```
1st: 1,2,3,4
2nd: 5,6,7,8
3rd: 9,10,11,12

3 * 4 = 12
```

X increments 12 times

Answer (score 1):

Outer loop *iterates* 3 times.
Inner loop *iterates* 4 times.
Since inner loop is *executed* 3 times, the body of the inner loop is *executed* 3 * 4 times, i.e. 12 times.

Executing `x++;` 12 times means that `x` is incremented by 12.
Starting at 0 means it ends up being **12**.